# Executing a command programatically in Eclipse console

Tags: console, eclipse-plugin

From my Eclipse plugin, I want to execute a command and show the results in the Console view (and later do some formatting and hyperlinking and pattern matching, which is done via the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners` extension point AFAIK). My question is how to do this? In plain Java, I would use a `ProcessBuilder`. Do I have to do this and bind the stdout/stderr somehow to a newly created console page or is there another way? Any pointers/experiences are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716615/writing-to-the-eclipse-console) and [the ProcessBuilder](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html), I managed to lazily create my console, show it and echo the input stream of the process to the console's message stream (instead of System.out).